# P0960, Is there any kind of mechanic to detect if there are narrowing in the new aggregates init with ()s in c++20?

Tags: c++, std, c++20, narrowing

With [P0960](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0960r3.html) "Allow initializing aggregates from a parenthesized list of values", you can do aggregates init with `()`s also.

However, this initialization allows narrowing while `{}`s doesn't.

```
#include <vector>
#include <climits>

struct Foo
{
  int x, y;
};

int main()
{
  // auto p = new Foo{INT_MAX, UINT_MAX}; // still won't compile
  auto q = new Foo(INT_MAX, UINT_MAX);    // c++20 allows narrowing aggregates init

  std::vector<Foo> v;
  // v.emplace_back(Foo{INT_MAX, UINT_MAX}); // still won't compile
  v.emplace_back(INT_MAX, UINT_MAX);         // c++20 allows narrowing aggregates init
                                             // in furtherly perfect forwardings
}
```

Is it possible to detect narrowing conversion with C++20 aggregate initialization with parentheses?

Comment: Are you looking for compiler specific answer?

Comment: @P.W "Anything"  I'm afraid that this standard move might lead to many subtle bugs because of unaware narrowing. More importantly, the perfect forwarding is literally "everywhere" now. If one can "restrict" narrowness where he or she feels uncomfortable, it must be such a relief.

Answer (score 7):

Paren-initializing aggregates permits narrowing conversions.

Constructors and aggregate-initialization behave differently, and the feature *looks like* a constructor invocation and so it is intentionally designed to *behave like* a constructor invocation as much as possible. All of the notable features of aggregate-initialization (narrowing converisons, lifetime extension for references, etc.) very intentionally do not exist int he paren-initialization case.

The only difference is that paren-initializing aggregates *does* evaluate the expressions left-to-right (whereas with a constructor call, we have indeterminate evaluation of arguments).

---

Specifically:

```
 auto q = new Foo(INT_MAX, UINT_MAX);
```

will behave mostly as if you had actually written this constructor:

```
struct Foo
{
  Foo(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) { } // ~ish
  int x, y;
};
```

Which itself does not warn on any compiler I tried today.

Comment: That example kills! But how do we restrict narrowness of initialization of "Foo" on the "outside" then?

Comment: @sandthorn Same way you do today - use `{}`s

Comment: I feel like to have something like `-frestrict-narrowing-paren-aggregates-init` across the board. So I do not miss where I miss `{ }`s myself.

Answer (score 5):

You are not supposed to want to "restrict narrowness" when using () initialization.

The main point of this feature is to allow the use of aggregates in forwarding scenarios, such as `container::emplace`, in-place constructors, and the like. They don't work at present because the `std::allocator_traits<>::construct` will not and *cannot* use list initialization syntax, since there are too many cases where it will hide constructors that you may want to call.

In forwarding scenarios, the ability to *accurately* cull out narrowing conversions is limited when dealing with aggregates. Why? Consider this:

```
struct Agg { int i; };

Agg a{5.0f};
```

That is not a narrowing conversion, because that particular floating-point literal value can be converted to an `int` with no loss of precision. However, when you are forwarding construction through `emplace` and the like, the compiler cannot see the actual value of the parameter. It only sees types. So if you were to do:

```
vector<Agg> v;
v.emplace_back(5.0f);
```

All the compiler sees is that `emplace_back` will try to pass a `float` to the aggregate initialization of `Agg`. That is always a narrowing conversion and therefore is always illegal.

List initialization's narrowing prevention makes some sense, as braced-init-lists are best used locally. The type being initialized is known, and any literal values will be provided directly where the `{}` is used. So there is sufficient information to deal with narrowing issues in a reasonable way.

Once you get into forwarding, this just doesn't work as well. Narrowing prevention will cull out parameters whose values locally would have been fine.

So the question is this: do you want `emplace(X, Y, Z)` to work just as well as `Agg{X, Y, Z}` did, for all valid X, Y, and Z? If the answer is yes, then `()` aggregate initialization cannot prevent narrowing.